# Separate alpha for UITabBar and UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I need to set alpha parameter for my UITabBar. I do that the following way:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.alpha = CGFloat(0.2)
```

Probably it works, but here is result:
[image]

As you can see UIBarButtonItem has alpha of 0.2 too. How can I set separate alpha for UITabBar and UITabBarItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of doing it with `alpha` property. Put background image to your UITabBar. This image can be just semi transparent png file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the alpha value, use a background image for the bar, with the desired alpha value.